# OCULink connector pin configuration for Root port and endpoint

Tags: pcie

We are using an OCUlink connector for the PCIe x4 interface in one of our new design which should support both root port and endpoint. We have a few queries to clarify on the same.

1. When our board is the root port, are the clock signals are must be provided for the OCUlink A12 and A13 pins? Similarly when our board is the endpoint what about the clock direction is it input to our design? or for board working as endpoint clock signals are not required?
2. Similar to the sideband signals (RST and PRSNT), when the board is the root port and board will generate the RST signal to the endpoint, when we use the board as endpoint RST signal is input the board, so these change of signal direction how we can take care in the design.
   I have attached here with the OCUlink pinout for rootport and endpoint, please clarify the above query , also if you have any reference design, please share with us
   [image]